# Do property lists save between app sessions?

Tags: ios, persistence, plist

I was wondering if property lists, (.plist) would save the contents if i were to exit the app and then re-open it. I would like to save a couple of variables to a plist so I could read from it every time I need some universal information about the user in my app.

1. Do plists save the variables if I were to close and reopen the app?
2. Should I be using plists or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use plist to save user infomation. This is a sample way. Make a plist and write to the sandbox.

```
NSString *urlStr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
urlStr = [urlStr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userInfo.dic"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
[userInfoDictionary writeToURL:url error:NULL];
```

You can also use SQLite database or Core Data if the information is complex.